# CakePHP: Unable to send emails as just plain text

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, html-email

CakePHP 2.+...

I'm looping through a list of users and sending each an email with the following method. The emails are all sent but the format seems to be text+html even when I specify that I want only plain text (`emailFormat('text)`). I wouldn't especially mind the html being included, but it screws up the formatting and most mail clients seem to choose the (ugly) HTML version to show by default. Specifically, the last line with the "PS: " is getting appended wrapped in `<pre>` tags so the fonts change. Urgh.

```
public function send_blast_to_user( $blast, $blastUser) {

    $body = $blast['Blast']['body'];
    $body = str_replace('%%FIRST_NAME%%', $blastUser['first_name'], $body);
    $body = str_replace('%%LAST_NAME%%', $blastUser['last_name'], $body);

    $body .= '

    PS: You can stop receiving these emails any time by changing your settigns: http://example.com/';

    $Email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
    $Email->from( $blast['Blast']['from'] );
    $Email->emailFormat('text');
    $Email->to( $blastUser['email'] );
    $Email->subject( $blast['Blast']['subject'] );
    $sent = $Email->send( $body );
    $Email->reset();
    if ($sent) {
        $blastUser['BlastsUser']['sent']++;
        $this->BlastsUser->save($blastUser['BlastsUser']);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The resulting email looks like this:

```
------------=_1385042226-22231-136
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable

Dear Emerson,=0D
=0D
You are perfect for the following job.=0D
=0D
From,=0D
Brett=0D
=0D
        PS: You can stop receiving these emails any time by changing your j=
ob alert settings: http://example.com/ bla=0D
=0D
=0D
=0D


------------=_1385042226-22231-136
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><body>
<p>Dear Emerson,</p>
<p>You are perfect for the following job.</p>
<p>From, Brett</p>
<pre>PS: You can stop receiving these emails any time by changing your job =
alert settigns: http://example.com/bla/ </pre>
</body></html>=

------------=_1385042226-22231-136--
```

Here's my email configurations in /Config/email.php

```
public $smtp = array(
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    'port' => 587,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'myusername',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'client' => null,
    'log' => false,
    'tls' => true
    //'charset' => 'utf-8',
    //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
);
```

Comment: Does it send both HTML and text/plain even if you do not specify `$Email->emailFormat('text');`?

Comment: @russellc Yes. It appears "both" is the default and my attempt to override it isn't working.

Comment: Is there anything special in your email configuration "smtp"? It was specified as the argument for the `CakeEmail` object constructor.

Comment: @russellc I don't think any of my config settings should effect this but I added it to the question above just in case.

Comment: Might be a long shot, but might this be a piece of the puzzle? http://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/200181418-Plain-text-emails-converted-to-HTML

Comment: @russellc You're right! Sendgrid appears to be ADDING the HTML formatting. If you submit this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Great to see we figured that one out! I've posted the answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like we figured it out!

The issue was due to SendGrid converting emails to HTML on their end when you use their service.

### An excerpt from the linked page:

If you are sending plain text emails, you may have noticed that, in some cases, your email is converted to HTML. This typically happens when you have one or more filters enabled that require a HTML version of the message you are sending.

Why does this happen?

The following filters convert plain text emails to HTML so the proper HTML tags can be inserted into the email:

Click tracking
Open tracking
Email template
Gravatar
How can I control the resulting conversion (see update below)

You can turn off the filters causing the conversion from plain text to HTML.
If you start each line with a space, this will add a "preformatted"  tag around the line.
You can separate new sentences with double newlines, which will add a "paragraph"

tag around the sentence.
You can convert your message to HTML, bypassing our need to convert it altogether

UPDATE:

You can now disable plain-text to HTML conversion globally or just for click tracking.

To disable conversion globally, visit Account->Global Settings and check the "Don't convert plain text emails to HTML" checkbox (See Example)
To disable conversion just for click tracking visit Filters and click on the settings link for Click Tracking. Ensure the checkbox "Enable click tracking in plain text emails" is unchecked (See Example)

### For reference:

Might be a long shot, but might this be a piece of the puzzle? http://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/200181418-Plain-text-emails-converted-to-HTML